# working with old versions of bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Will there be a problem in using older versions of bootstrap? Currently i am still working with bootstrap 3.3.5. Should I start using the latest version of bootstrap? Or using the older version will never give me problems.

Answer (score 1):

You will very likely not run into problems.Looking at the [release history](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases). Bootstrap fixes on 3.x series are bug fixes in edge cases and improvements in newer browsers.

Bootstrap 4.x is a new framework with some big changes on how things work. Mostly modernizing bootstrap to work with flexbox, which is the modern approach for layout.

The main benefit of upgrading bootstrap is typically new features and a bug fix

Answer (score 0):

Its matter of choise. If you use old version of bottstrap you cant be enable to use new features. Every new version of bottstrap is fully tested and working fine.